# Datatable server side in Or condition SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

Hi I got trouble in my project,

So my logic sql is :

```
SELECT 
 brand, 
 purchase_date, 
 type 
FROM 
 cars 
WHERE 
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30')
    AND brand = 'BMW' 
  OR  
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30') 
    AND brand = 'Honda'
```

Thats sql work with datatables, but when I do searching in datatable its become like this : (Take a look at additional 'AND' in script below)

```
WHERE 
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30')
    AND brand = 'BMW' 
  OR  
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30') 
    AND brand = 'Honda'
    AND type = 'suv'
```

This one is not correct and should be :

```
WHERE 
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30')
    AND brand = 'BMW' 
    AND type = 'suv'
  OR  
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30') 
    AND brand = 'Honda'
    AND type = 'suv'
```

So how can I modify datatable searching or sorting logic in OR mySQL logic ?
Anyhelp will appreciate.

Comment: Can you please explain clearly..... Its not understandable.

Comment: You may have forgot some parentheses if your indentation is right `WHERE (
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30')
    AND brand = 'BMW' )
  OR  (
    (purchase_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-11-30') 
    AND brand = 'Honda')`

Comment: You know that mixing lots of ANDs and ORs without a suitable set of brackets defining what is grouped with what, is a quick way to a world of pain, right?